# How to get emoji working in elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno

I am trying to get emoji to work in Juno.

Since I installed a couple of weeks ago, it has not worked for me. [I see only an empty emoji picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaZkQ.png). I have tried to use Ideogram from the AppCentre, but it also displays no emoji, just empty categories like the system one.

[I also asked on Reddit about this](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/bed333/how_can_i_get_emoji_working/). I followed the instructions provided to me there, but they have not been successful.

Has anybody else had an issue with emoji? Is there a way to "reset" back to a working configuration? I was under the impression that in Juno it should be working out of the box.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working right after installation of the app. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Ideogram? Perhaps the font pack didn’t get installed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Interestingly, I can see that the Noto Color Emoji font is installed in the fonts app. It's just never worked in a picker of any sort since day one. Other articles seem to suggest that it should "just work". But what about when it doesn't?

Comment: Same issue. Fonts are there, just the list of emoji is empty. Even Characters app emoji list displays no emoji, even though is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm getting the same problem, but recently discovered Emote, which seems a more functional alternative: https://snapcraft.io/install/emote/elementary